# Necessito alterar o output de uma variável no Python

Tags: python, array

A minha variável `a`, importada de um ficheiro `.mat`, tem como output:

`array([[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]])`.

Necessito que o output da variável `a` seja: `array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`

Como realizo esta correção/alteração no Python?

Comment: Tem como colocar um exemplo testável pois quando fala array em python fica ambíguo, pois não dá para saber se está falando [disso](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/array.html), [disso](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) ou [disso](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list). Dependendo do que for o problema pode ser resolvido na leitura.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adiciona a seguinte linha:

`a = [i[0] for i in a]`

Você tem uma lista de listas. Essa compressão ai vai pegar o primeiro elemento de cada lista e colocar em uma nova lista.

Caso possa existir mais de um elemento em cada lista... tipo `a = [[0, 1, 2],[3, 4],[5]]`, você talvez queira algo mais genérico como:

`a = [i for j in a for i in j]`

Comment: Muito obrigado!!! Problema resolvido!